# Wordpress. Ultimate Member Plugin. Registraion form not redirecting

Tags: php, wordpress, ultimate-member

Good Day

I am having an issue with a Registration form from Ultimate Member, when a user clicks "Register" the site redirects to the registration page again.

I have tried the following:
1-> I made sure that my settings at UM -> User Role -> Subscribers is set correctly. I set the registration options to "Auto Approve" and action after registration to "Redirect to URL" and I specified the URL.
This does not work for some reason as it just redirects back to the registration page. My default user is Subscriber so I am sure that it is the correct roll to be changing.

Please note
On the back-end the user account is created after they submit the registration form.

Comment: You should open a ticket to the maintainer of the plugin..

Answer (score 0):

Here's some things to try:

1. Make sure your redirect URL in the role page is in the format `/slug/` (note the leading and trailing slashes).
2. Check the URL by navigating to it manually to see if you get the expected page or a "404 not found" error.
3. Check that the UM form you are using is set to be for the role "Subscriber".
4. Make sure the registration form number in the shortcode on your registration page matches the form number you are trying to use in the UM forms list.
5. Check that the checkboxes in the UM forms settings (approval, redirect URL, etc) are set the way you intend. (Sometimes, clicking on the sentences next to the checkboxes in that admin page can check or uncheck those checkboxes unintentionally).

I have only used Ultimate Member with custom roles rather than the default WP roles, so not sure if that is something to consider also?

Comment: Thank you, I've double checked what you mentioned and unfortunately get the same error. I am now looking into the custom roles to see if that will resolve my issue.

Comment: In that case, submit a request to the plugin author. The method of doing this (wordpress plugin support vs ultimate member support), and the expected response time, will depend on whether you are on the free version or a paid version of UM.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Registration form in the form builder section of ultimate builder, for me personally the problem was "force strong passwords" option and it never gave an error to re-enter a stronger on, but instead it submitted the form to later be rejected by PHP and thus no user is created and eventually not redirecting the new user.

Thank you.